# Previous entry before first zero SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

given the following table:

```
id (desc) | amount
------------------
9         | 3 
8         | 2
7         | 1 <- RETURN THIS ROW
6         | 0
5         | 1
4         | 0
3         | 2
2         | 1
1         | 0
```

I need to return only one row - that one with the id 7

Rules: 
- the most recent entry have an amount bigger than 0
- should return the row after the first amount 0 occurence

That way if I have:

```
id (desc) | amount
------------------
4         | 0
3         | 0
2         | 1
1         | 0
```

It will not show any row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when amount = 0 then id end) over () as last_0_id
      from t
     ) t
where id > last_0_id
order by id asc
limit 1;
```

Or, without window functions:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select max(t2.id) as id
      from t t2
      where t2.amount = 0
     ) t2
     on t.id > t2.id
order by id asc
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e3fc345a917066425d138e925a839801) is a db<>fiddle

This is probably faster than using `lead()`, actually.

Comment: . . . This would not return any result.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . I see.  The ids go in the wrong direction.  I fixed the answer.